# How to display Changing post link for 24 hours in x category

Tags: posts

**Here is an example**

Cat 1 has 6 post:
( post 1 , post 2 , post 3, post 4 etc.. )

Cat 2 has 6 post:
( post 1 , post 2 , post 3, post 4 etc.. )

**i want to display random post like this:**

Today's CAT 1 Random post : Post 2
Today's CAT 2 Random Post : Post 5

but the posts has to change per 24 hours. Is it possible. Thanks

( Sorry about my bad Eng )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use get_posts() to return a random post, but it would change every time the page loaded.  So, here's an idea for you.

In a plugin file, set up a [wp_cron](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) hook.

```
<?php
/* Your plugin header goes here */

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse24234_activation' );
function wpseo24234_activation()
{
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'wpse24234_daily' );
}
```

Then hook a function into your cron action that grabs a random post (via get_posts()) and stores it in a [transient](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) that expires every 24 hours.

```
add_action( 'wpse24234_daily', 'wpse24234_daily_cb' );
function wpse24234_daily_cb()
{
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'cat' => YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_HERE, 'numberposts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand' ) );
    if( ! empty( $posts ) )
        set_transient( 'cat_1_post', $posts[0]->ID, 60 * 60 * 12 );
}
```

Then on the front end, you can get the post ID with get transient, and use the ID to pull in whatever other stuff you'd like.

```
<?php
/* Somewhere on your site */
$id = get_transient( 'cat_1_post' );

$link = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $id ) . '</a>';
?>

Todays random post from Category 1 is <?php echo $link; ?>
```

You'll have to do some testing to see if this will work for you, of course.

Comment: thank you so much Christopher Davis ;) i m gonna try it r now

Comment: it didnt work :S Davis.

Comment: That's why I said you'd have to test it! Did you put it into a plugin file and active the plugin?

Comment: yes. i added all codes my themes functions.php and i added the last code to my sidebar.php. The result comes but that post link not from the choosen category it choosen from the all categories. Ps. I edited the YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_HERE line too.

Comment: That would explain why it didn't work.  You have to call wp_schedule_event one time (on plugin activation), there's not a theme activation hook to do that.  Take a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers that's what I meant by `/* your plugin header goes here */`

Comment: Ok. Now i created a Plug-in and activated it. But it says the same thing.
The plugin file is here :http://2shared.com/file/TAW9aZ6V/gununyemekleri.html whats wrong with that.

Comment: Davis did u get my e mail.?

Comment: * anybody help ?